# How do I beat level 6-3 in SPY Mouse using only 1 pipe?

Tags: ios, spy-mouse

One of the challenges on level 6-3 is to beat the level using only 1 pipe. Although I can easily beat the level, no matter how many times I try, I just can't manage to beat the level using only 1 pipe. What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw the ghost cats down to the very bottom of screen. Wait in the middle of screen until they are almost upon you.  Then, wait again by the entrance to the blue pipe.  When they are almost there (I mean just about on you) jump through to the top.  Wait again for them to just about get to you.  Sneak past the top ghost and go just past the shadow area.  Then come down to the area on the middle left, where three pieces of cheese are.  Wait again until they are just about on you - scamper past the lowest ghost and immediately go for the cheese.  Turn around and run for the door.

Had to try several times, but eventually got it a couple of times.

Comment: There is only one piece of cheese in this level. You surely refer to a different level.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the blue pipe.  Nip down to the three hearts on the RHS and then sneak along the bottom then the left of the corridor back into the shaded area. Then come out nip along to the purple tube entrance wait till they almost there nip through go straight for cheese and head for balloon and door